# How can I stabilize a machine learning model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, random-forest, xgboost

I have a data to train the model. Also, I have another data to test the performance of the model as weekly. However, it seems that the model is not stable. There are some difference between training scores and weekly test scores. On the other hand, it is a fraud problem and I am using XGBoosting method. How can I make stable the model ? I can use different algorithms and parameters.

```
parameters = {
    'n_estimators':[100],
    'max_depth':[5],
    'learning_rate':[0.1],
    'classifier__min_sample_leaf':[5],
    'classifier__criterion':['gini']
}

xgboost = XGBClassifier(scale_pos_weight=30)

xgboost_gs = GridSearchCV(xgboost, parameters, scoring='recall', cv=5, verbose=False)

xgboost_gs.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

[image]

Comment: you can give a try for deep learning methods like keras or tensorflow. You can use this setup to check if it is working properly https://www.kaggle.com/dakshmiglani/credit-card-fraudulent-detection-with-dnn-keras

Answer (score 2):

I also worked on a similar project, and it's very difficult to improve the model's kappa or f1 score .... This is a problem that a lot of people face (data imbalance), specially in this field. I tried several models, feature engineering  data cleaning and nothing seemed to work,I managed to improve kappa by 2 % by oversampling the unbalanced class (smote did not improve or any synthetic data creation)

But it's not all bad news! What I found out is that different models yield different results in terms of false positives/false negatives.

So the question is, what do you/your company want to prioritise on? A model that has less false negatives (classified fraud but it's not actually fraud, probably this one, more conservative) or less false positives (Classified as not fraud but it's actually fraud ) It's a trade play around and find the model that solves your problem, do not only look to accuracy on kappa or F1! Confusion Matrix in this case will help you!

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Actually, I am working on imbalanced data. But I used (scale_pos_weight=30) parameter to make a balance. Also, I am scoring model with 'recall' score. I prefer less False Negative. How can i do that ? Thank you again.

Comment: Yes recall is good, my suggestion is to try as many models as you can and check the confusion matrix and see which ones produce the least amount of false negatives! I remember that SVM was particularly good for my data set in terms of FP, it will depend on the dataset and also on the model! Try different parameters etc I would advice you to create some sort of automation towards where you input a list of models and it trains the models by itself or something like that! 
Hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

You only have 24 items for the 1 class. This is too little so you will have to do some sampling to get both classes close to the same amount. This is to so fraud detection where you can easily get 1000s of non-fraud cases but only a hand full of fraud cases.

You can use some sampling method like SMOTE where you oversample the class with fewer observations and under-sample the class with more observations to let them have the same number of events for each class.

So in short you need a good balanced dataset for training. I am assuming that you had too few cases of class 1 in the training set

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Actually, the photo is not training scores. In training data, there are 72 fraud, 1897 non-fraud records. Yes, I need to make a balance between them and to do that I am using scale_pos_weight parameter.